# Table of TextFiels in blazor

Tags: blazor

I want to make a table of textfields for each row and column. Ideally it shall be possible to expand each row and column by a button of some sort. I'm using Blazor and I'm kinda new to programming so I don't really have a clue how to do this. Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
@code {
    private string[,] textInput = new string [100,100];
    private int rows = 2;
    private int cols = 2;
}

<table class="table">
@for (var i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    <tr>
    @for (var j=0; j<cols; j++) {
        int rowindex = i;
        int colindex = j;
        <td>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" @bind=@textInput[rowindex, colindex] />
        </td>
    }
    </tr>
}
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=@(() => rows = rows == 100 ? 100 : rows + 1)>Add row</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=@(() => rows = rows == 1 ? 1 : rows - 1)>Remove row</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=@(() => cols = cols == 100 ? 100 : cols + 1)>Add column</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=@(() => cols = cols == 1 ? 1 : cols - 1)>Remove column</button>
```